Sending message from background.js to all tabs' content.js (mv3)
I am getting an error with not being able to establish a connection from background to content. I want the background to be able to send a message to every instance of the content page to globally run a function for all tabs. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have been stuck on this for hours. Thank you!
Error:
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
content.js:
// Message listener from background.js to execute a function in this content script
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, _sender, _sendResponse) => {
    if (message.action === "resetTimer") {
        resetInactiveTimer();
    }
});

background.js:
if (message.action == "globalResetTimer") {
        // Reset timer in all tabs
        chrome.tabs.query({}, function (tabs) {
            for (var i=0; i<tabs.length; ++i) {
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[i].id, { action: "resetTimer"});
            }
        });
    }

manifest.json:
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content.js"],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    }
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },


I tried your code and it works for me in Chrome (version 126).
So there must be something else that you are doing in your extension.
Are you making sure that the tabs have been opened/updated after the extension was installed? If a website is opened before the extension is installed, the content script won't be injected properly.
A similar issue is if you call chrome.runtime.reload() somewhere in your extension but don't reload the tabs you want to send a message to.
An alternative approach, but this works only in specific use cases, would be to use the chrome.scripting.executeScript() functionality.
